# how to match keys to an alphabetic sort in SQL

Tags: mysql

so I have a table, which I'll simplify:

(and by the way this is a legacy so the idx column can't be removed and just go purely alphabetic)

```
components
----------
id int(11) unsigned
idx mediumint(4) unsigned
value char(100)
```

here is a sample of a "out of synch" listing

```
1   1   apples
2   2   bananas
3   3   cherries
4   4   aaron
```

I was thinking I could have a table that was just one column with number values of 1 to a large quantity, and somehow do a join on these two tables, and thereby do an update on the previous table so that the idx values numbered from 1 to 4 to match aaron through cherries respectively.  Does anyone have a solution like that, or any other for that matter, that is a pure MySQL query?

[EDIT: the actual join of tables is more complex and @barranca posted a incrementing query that "almost" works.  Here is the *actual* query that I'm doing with all related tables:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Idx, a.Components_ID, c.Label, @n := @n + 5 AS NewIdx
FROM (SELECT @n := 0) as init, (em__assemblies a JOIN em__node_components c ON a.Components_ID=c.ID)
WHERE a.Groupings_ID=26
ORDER BY c.Label
```

I used a five to make it clear to myself that the sorting is happening AFTER the incrementing

Comment: Why do you want the index values to match the alphabetic ordering? Why not just do the alphabetic ordering in your queries?

Comment: Tip: instead of posting your question to include the answer, post an answer (yes, you can answer your own questions). it's cleaner, and it helps future readers

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think that the `idx` column is not needed (you'll see why in a moment).

If all you need is to show an integer column that "matches" the order of `value`, you can use a variable:

```
select id, @n := @n + 1 as idx, value /*edit:it was n + 1, changed it to @n + 1*/
from
    (select @n := 0) as init
    , components
order by components.value
```

If you want to update the `idx` table, I think a stored procedure could do the trick:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure update_idx()
begin
    declare this_id, n int unsigned;
    declare done int default false;
    declare cur_values cursor for select id from components order by value;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
    open cur_values;
    set n = 1;
    loop_update: loop
        fetch cur_values into this_id;
        if done then
            leave cur_values;
        end if;
        -- Update the table
        update components set idx = n where id = this_id;
        set n = n + 1;
    end loop;
    close cur_values;
end $$
delimiter ;
-- Call it:
call update_idx();
```

---

A working example using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58daa/2):

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table example(
  id int unsigned not null primary key,
  idx int unsigned,
  value char(100)
);

insert into example
values (1,1,'apples'),(2,2,'bananas'),(3,3,'cherries'),(4,4,'aaron');
```

**Query 1** (the *original* data):

```
select * from example;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58daa/2/0)**:

```
| ID | IDX |    VALUE |
|----|-----|----------|
|  1 |   1 |   apples |
|  2 |   2 |  bananas |
|  3 |   3 | cherries |
|  4 |   4 |    aaron |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select id, @n := @n+1 as idx, value
from (select @n := 0) as init, example
order by value;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58daa/2/1)**:

```
| ID | IDX |    VALUE |
|----|-----|----------|
|  4 |   1 |    aaron |
|  1 |   2 |   apples |
|  2 |   3 |  bananas |
|  3 |   4 | cherries |
```

Comment: I really appreciate the detail you provided.  If I can get the first query to work, no stored procedure is needed since I can join the orig. table on your first query, and just do an update.  BUT see my edit above and your username, as the actual query was more complex, and it appears the incrementing happens before the sorting does, so it doesn't work.  Again, thank you for helping me learn something new!

Comment: @SamuelFullman Check [this SQL fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58daa/2), it does work